# Non-Destructive Mirror of a Multires Modifier Sculpt

Tags: modeling, modifiers, sculpting, mirror, multiresolution

I am in the process of modeling a simple couch. I am sculpting in fabric details using the multi-resolution modifier and various cloth brushes. I'm running into a problem after modeling the first armrest. All I want to do is duplicate it and then mirror it along the X so I don't have to start from scratch.

See this image:

---

[image: Image 1]

So I duplicate A, position it where I want, and then mirror it by setting X to -1.000. Everything looks peachy so-far. See this image:

---

[image: Image 2]

If I try to sculpt at this stage, I get a warning that my scale is non-uniform. Sculpting is a big buggy if I ignore the warning. So I need to apply the scale somehow without losing the data from the multiresolution modifier. Unfortunately if I apply the scale, I lose a lot of the sculpting detail. See this image:

---

[image: Image 3]

So my question is, how can I mirror the first armrest and still retain the multires modifier data? Is this not possible due to the nature of how the modifier works? Is there another (better) way to do this?

Thanks much.

Comment: Is there a reason you are copying the object and inverting it instead of using a mirror modifier?

Comment: If I use the mirror modifier after the multi-resolution modifier I can't sculpt asymmetrically. I want to be able to sculpt freely on both arm-rests. If I apply the mirror, this weirdness results: https://i.imgur.com/PC995nw.png

Comment: If you don't wanna use mirror modifier...You can select both the armset and the go on what ever you want to do. By this you can move them freely and don't need to mirror the object...

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you completely. I'm trying to duplicate and mirror an object in one stage of sculpting while _retaining_ the sculpting data from the multiresolution modifier. I want to mirror the object to save time so I have a "base" to sculpt from rather than doing the same thing again. Sorry if my explanation is confusing.

Comment: You can do edit both armset at the same time by selecting both of them...

Comment: any reason why you can't duplicate the mesh in edit mode then sculpt, then use <kbd>p</kbd> to separate it once your done sculpting? or am I misunderstanding

Comment: Yes. If you do that, the duplicated mesh is not mirrored thus defeating the purpose. If you mirror it in edit mode the same thing happens if you were to mirror the mesh in object mode. The sculpting/multires data still "thinks" the mesh is not mirrored and the mesh gets corrupted. I've already created the second armrest by hand, but I still want to know if there is a solution to this - out of curiosity. I have a feeling it's a limitation of the multiresolution modifier though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Animation Nodes](https://animation-nodes.com) add-on, it is open-source and totally free. I'd suggest a setup like this:

[image]

The node tree duplicates `A` then modify its scale (new `y` = `y`*(-1)). In your case, you may want to do it with `x` instead. I tried to sculpt `A`.  After I mouse-released the sculpt brush, `B` would be updated too. In this approach, I can't sculpt the new object (so-called `B`) directly.

[image]

[image]

This issue as well as a few similar ones will be solved by [Everything Nodes project](https://developer.blender.org/T67088) for vanilla Blender but the implementation is not done yet and there is still a long way to go.

---

Here are some of Chris-P's **Animation Nodes** [Youtube tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fruLQhn4wWg). I have no affiliation with the author. However, the first few episodes of the series were very useful to me as beginner. *Feel free to comment about better tutorial please.*

Answer (score 1):

I have two solutions

A)

1. dublicate object.
2. press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>+<kbd>XYZ</kbd> (flip object on x/y/z axis).
3. place it in the desired place.

B)
This doesn't flip the object, but it gets you a similar result.

1. select the couch, and then press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> (Cursor to selected).
2. Duplicate A and select the new object.
3. Set the transform pivot point to `3D Cursor`.
4. press <kbd>R</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>+<kbd>180</kbd> (rotate along z axis 180d).

Answer (score 0):

Hello my apologies if I am getting confused but you are trying to solve something by taking a strange detour. Follow these instructions to work in a happy way.

1 create a cube, subdivide it by 3 and apply the modifier. It's just so you have a bit of resolution.

2 in edit mode select all the vertices and move them in the X where the armrest would be left or right where you want.

3 You go into sculpt mode. Pressing N to see the right panel. In that panel at the bottom you see an option that says "Symmetrize" if you display it mark X to make symmetry in X just below that sub-panel you have a button to execute the symmetry if your object disappears is because you have to invert the direction, control z to see the object again and just above the Symmetrize button that you pressed you have a drop-down that says -x to + x because it searches for + x to -x symmetrize again and you will see the two hypothetical parts or armrests.

4 Now to model your two parts at the same time you have to verify that at the top of the toolbar the mirror symbol and xyz appear in three little buttons. It goes without saying that now you have to activate x to mirror.

Two things to keep in mind if you deactivate it, you will stop modeling in the mirror making different wrinkles for the two armrests. Therefore, do not click on the Symmetrize button or you will lose one of the sides replaced by the other and they will be the same again.

The other thing to keep in mind is that if you stop mirroring and make marks on one of the sides, you still have the option to activate the x again but if you model above the parts that are no longer the same, it may be in some area the brush no longer touches the surface if you made an indentation or touch it too much because you made a ridge. In any case, you can do it, just check that you like the result.

As a recommendation, try not to. I would first model everything that I do want to be reflected and then what I don't want to be reflected. Note do not apply uv before modeling. if you press the Simmetryze button this makes a destructive reflex. So that you understand me, the reflection generates a copy of vertices with an index different from the one they had, it did not move them so that they were reflected. I generate them. If your object had uV now your second half in the uv editor are overlapping. Taking advantage of half of your texture map.